How to store and fetch browser passwords using Playwright
Holla,
I have a usercase where I need to store credentials in password manager of Chrome and other browsers. I tried using Playwright to achieve it but sadly, it's not storing the user and password for a given site.
The way I want to make sure it works is by opening chrome after the execution and see that the password is stored in password manager.
I would appreciate help with it
The code (note, it's only implamented for chrome currently, so I know that .. no need to let me know it's not working with something else :)):
import argparse
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


class BrowserAutomation:
    def __init__(self, user_data_dir, username, password, browser_type='chromium', headless=True):
        self.user_data_dir = user_data_dir
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.browser_type = browser_type
        self.headless = headless

    def load_passwords(self):
        with sync_playwright() as p:
            if self.browser_type == 'chromium':
                browser = p.chromium.launch_persistent_context(self.user_data_dir, headless=self.headless, args=['--enable-features=PasswordImport','--password-store=basic'], channel="chrome")
            elif self.browser_type == 'firefox':
                browser = p.firefox.launch_persistent_context(self.user_data_dir, headless=self.headless)
            elif self.browser_type == 'webkit':
                browser = p.webkit.launch_persistent_context(self.user_data_dir, headless=self.headless)
            elif self.browser_type == 'edge':
                browser = p.chromium.launch_persistent_context(self.user_data_dir, headless=self.headless, channel='msedge')
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Unsupported browser type: {self.browser_type}")

            page = browser.new_page()

            # Verify if the password was saved
            page.goto('chrome://password-manager/passwords')
            page.click('#addPasswordButton')
            page.fill('input[aria-label="Site"]', 'https://www.google.com')
            page.fill('input[aria-label="Username"]', self.username)
            page.fill('input[aria-label="Password"]', self.password)
            page.click('#addButton')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Load passwords to browser.')
    parser.add_argument('-data_dir', type=str, help='User data directory')
    parser.add_argument('-u', type=str, help='Username for login')
    parser.add_argument('-p', type=str, help='Password for login')
    parser.add_argument('-browser', type=str, choices=['chromium', 'firefox', 'webkit', 'edge'], help='Type of browser')
    parser.add_argument('--headless', action='store_true', help='Run browser in headless mode')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    automation = BrowserAutomation(user_data_dir=args.data_dir,
                                   username=args.u,
                                   password=args.p,
                                   browser_type=args.browser,
                                   headless=args.headless)
    automation.load_passwords()

    print("Browser automation and Flask server have both terminated.")


I doubt and hope that you/any third party program can access this data of the browser easily.

Everything is doable :)

Doable yes, but as I said: maybe not easy. I mean, passwords should be protected

Just closing the loop. I was able to do it with accessing directly to the password section and adding the password in.
